# Complex time series queries in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm not very familiar with problem solving with SQL, thus the question.

I've the following table structure in `Hive`.

```
candidate_id | source_stage  | destination_stage  | date
12345        | IN_REVIEW     | IN_REVIEW          | 2020-05-01
12345        | IN_REVIEW     | SCREEN             | 2020-05-07
23456        | IN_REVIEW     | SCREEN             | 2020-05-07
12345        | SCREEN        | INTERVIEW          | 2020-05-09
23456        | SCREEN        | INTERVIEW          | 2020-05-07
```

The hierarchy of stages is as follows:

```
IN_REVIEW -> SCREEN -> INTERVIEW -> OFFER -> HIRED
```

I want to write two queries that answers the following question:

1. How many candidates moved from `IN_REVIEW` to `SCREEN` between `$start_date` AND `$end_date`?
2. How much time does it take to hire a candidate - stated otherwise time taken to move from `IN_REVIEW` to `HIRED` between `$start_date` AND `$end_date`?

Comment: This looks like two questions to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is just filtering and counting:

```
select count(*) cnt
from mytable
where 
    source_stage = 'IN_REVIEW' 
    and destination_stage = 'SCREEN'
    and date >= ?
    and date <  ?
```

The second question can be solved using conditional aggregation (assuming that a candidate cannot have the same stage more than once):

```
select 
    candidate_id, 
    datediff(
        max(case when destination_stage = 'HIRED'     then date end),
        max(case when destination_stage = 'IN_REVIEW' then date end)
    ) diff,
from mytable 
where date >= ? and date < ?
group by candidate_id
```

This gives you one row per `candidate` that had an event during the period, with the overall process duration (or `null` if the candidate's process did start or complete during the period).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. One quick question, how do I aggregate the second query to calculate something like total time to hire or average time to hire?

Comment: @root; you need another level of aggregation like: `select avg(diff) avg_diff from (... <second query here> ...)`

Comment: I'm really not that deep with SQL, I need to write one query that takes the date filters and provides total/avg time to hire during runtime. Could you modify your query to compose something like that?

Comment: @root: you can just turn the second query to a subquery, as showned in my previous comment.